# Auto adjust window width based on number of windows?

Tags: window, frames, window-splitting

If i run `C-x 3`, when emacs  starts  up it will split window and creates two windows of  **equal size** like this
[image]

Now i run  `C-x 3` again it  will split current window  into two parts resulting  in this

[image]

But whenver i  create a vertical split, i want to auto adjust width of each window to equal size like this.

[image]
How can  i achieve this?

Comment: You can press "C-x +" after splitting to make all windows evenly spaced. Handy to have in your muscle memory.

Comment: @InHarmsWay is there a hook which will run after creating window?

Comment: That I'm not sure, but you could always define your own command that calls the two functions you need. Logically the same as a hook, and allows you to continue calling the original functions separately if desired.

Comment: @InHarmsWay thats fine, post it as answer?

Comment: Try the `window-configuration-change-hook`. However you may want to bind your own split commands for this instead as @InHarmsWay suggested. Using the hook would likely have side effects you don't want with commands that split windows for other purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own command for this.  This allows you to use it when desired, but not change the default behavior of the original commands, keeping them useful individually if desired:

```el
  (defun my/split-window-evenly ()
    (interactive)
    (split-window-right)
    (balance-windows))

(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'my/split-window-evenly)
```